# installing R kernel to jupyter notebook in a different conda environment

Tags: python, r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have a conda environment containing all packages for jupyter notebook (say it's called `jupyter_env`. In a different conda environment I have R installed including `r-irkernel` (say the env is called `R_env`).

For python kernels I can easily make a python kernel in a specific environment (called e.g. `pyth27`) available to my jupyter installation in a different environment:

`(pyth27) > python -m ipykernel install --prefix=/path/to/jupyter/env --name "python27"`

Is there anything similar possible for the R kernel? So far I can only run the R kernel using a jupyter installation within the same environment(`R_env`).

One solution might be the `nb-conda_kernels` package. However there I'm not clear if it always adds all available kernels from all environments or whether I can specify which environments should be searched.

My question is similar to this one https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/397. Only that I don't want to use the base environment to start jupyter but a dedicated environment.

Answer (score 0):

As described on https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel, the `r-ikernel` package provides a mechanism similar to `python -m ipykernel install`, to be run in R:

```
R> IRkernel::installspec()
```

To run this from Bash, you can do

```bash
(R_env)> Rscript -e "IRkernel::installspec()"
```

**Now the tricky part**, due to Jupyter and R being in different environments: According to https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/499, `IRkernel::installspec()` requires the `jupyter-kernelspec` command. I've tested two methods to provide it (to be done before issuing the above commands):

- `jupyter-kernelspec` is part of Jupyter and hence in the file tree of `jupyter_env`, so add its path to `PATH` (I found it's better to add to the end so as to not disrupt other path lookups during the `Rscript` call)

  ```bash
  (R_env)> export PATH="$PATH:</path/to/conda>/envs/jupyter_env/bin"
  ```
- `jupyter-kernelspec` is included in the `jupyter_client` conda package, so you can do

  ```bash
  (R_env)> conda install jupyter_client
  ```

  Caveat: this installs a number of dependencies, including Python.

I opted for the first method to keep `R_env` free of Python packages.